# Does anyone have a SlickGrid wrapper for Haxe?

Tags: wrapper, slickgrid, haxe

I am using the Haxe multi-platform programming tool (http://haxe.org) which, among other things, can generate JavaScript output.  I would like to know if anyone has already done a "wrapper" library to interface Haxe with SlickGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like one exists yet... sorry!

Unless someone has made one but just not shared it.  Could be worth asking on the haxe [mailing list / google group](http://groups.google.com/group/haxelang/topics)?  You'll get a wider audience than on stack overflow.

If it looks like no one has done it, you can write your own... it's probably quite do-able.  And not too hard either.  I'd be happy to help you figure it out as you go... cause I might want to use it one day too :)

If you do decide to take that route I think the best option is to post on the mailing list, and we can help you out from there.  There's also a document on the wiki with some instructions:

http://haxe.org/doc/js/extern_libraries

This stuff is always a bit daunting when you first get started, but don't be afraid to ask for help and hopefully you'll be up and running in no time.